# Remove Nth Node From End of List(Leetcode)? - Python

Tags: python, linked-list, reverse

Link - https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/

My approach :

```
class Solution:
    def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: ListNode, n: int) -> ListNode:
        h = head
        td = h

        c = 0
        while head.next is not None:
            c+=1
            print(c,n)
            if c>n:
                td = td.next
            head = head.next
        if c + 1 != n:
            td.next = td.next.next
        return h
```

It fails in border cases like, [1,2] and n = 2, any way to modify this so that this works for all boarder cases and get accepted? (I know we can solve this using slow and fast pointers)

Comment: Your code is not even pythonic...

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Comment: First if you are using a python class you need to define what 'self' is in def__init__(). Then, 'def removeNthFromEnd(self, head: ListNode, n: int) -> ListNode:' is not the way you are supposed to define a function its variables. Could you check if you make some errors in  copying?

Comment: It's just leetcode's way of wrapping things and let us know what's expected. Its similar to "  def removeNthFromEnd(self, head, n):" and "ListNode" is defined for us. Our only job is to correctly write the function, that's it. That is where my logic is failing, just have a look at it as logic perspective.

Comment: But I am afraid that is not SO's way of asking a question, here you'd better give a minimally reproducible example of your codes and input.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted an alternative solution in case you were interested.

```
class Solution:
    def removeNthFromEnd(self, head, n):
        fast = slow = head
        for _ in range(n):
            fast = fast.next
        if not fast:
            return head.next
        while fast.next:
            fast = fast.next
            slow = slow.next
        slow.next = slow.next.next
        return head
```

Answer (score 0):

We use two pointers technique. "fast_pointer" must be "n" step ahead of "slow_pointer", so when we reach the end of the list, the slow pointer will be the node we are trying to delete.

Let's say we have 5 nodes and we want to delete the 2nd node from the end.

[image]

When we reach the end of the list, "slow_pointer" will point to the node that we want to remove. but how are we going to remove it? In order to remove a node from the linked list, its previous node should point to the its next node. In this example, we want to delete the 3rd node, so 2nd node.next should be pointing to the 4th node, since we have no reference of 3rd node, it will be garbage collected, will be removed.

So, we are going to create a dummy node, its value is not important but its next will be pointing to the "head" of the linked list. And our slow pointer will be starting from dummy.

[image]

```
class Solution:
    def remove(self,head:ListNode,n:int)->ListNode:
        dummy=ListNode(0,head)
        slow=dummy
        fast=head
        while n>0 and fast:
            fast=fast.next
            n-=1
        while fast:
            slow=slow.next
            fast=fast.next
        # now delete it
        slow.next=slow.next.next
        return dummy.next


class ListNode:
    def __init__(self,val,next=None):
        self.val=val
        self.next=next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def removeNthFromEnd(self, head ,n):
        
        temp = dummy = head
        
        count = 0
        
        if head.next == None:
            return None
        
        while head.next != None:
            count = count + 1
            
            if count > n:
                dummy = dummy.next
                
            head = head.next
        
        
        if count + 1 != n:
            dummy.next = dummy.next.next
            
        return temp
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).